# IIF parameter with two condition on same row

Tags: reporting-services

I'm creating a new report where one of my flags as to do with the Taxes we have here in Quebec. In this report, I'm displaying invoices with a header, the details (items) and then the total with the taxes.
Now here in Quebec we have TPS and TVQ as taxes. Sometimes, when we sell outside of the Quebec area at one of our other branch, we wont have the TVQ.

The goal of my flag, is to turn the textbox red when TPS is there and TVQ isn't there. I also want to do the same thing if TVQ is there and TPS isn't.

I kinda feel like it should look a little like that

IIF ((Fields!TAXDLID.Value = "TPS") AND (Fields!TAXDLID.Value = "TVQ"), black, red)

but I can't wrap my head around.

Thanks for the help!

edit:
[Here is something that works and doesn't need red flags](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d9pay.png)

[Here is something that also works and doesn't need red flags](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZUxBk.png)

[Here is something that does not work and would need a flags since it doesn't have TVQ](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RV1mN.png)

It's also possible to have nothing in the section

Comment: Your expression won't work as `TAXDLID` can't be both values at the same time. Can you share a sample of your dataset output and the expected results based on that same sample data.

Comment: @AlanSchofield I've edited the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not perfectly clear what your dataset looks like (from your dataset query) so I have made some assumptions as follows:

1. Each row in your dataset has a Column that is either 'TPS' or 'TVQ'
2. Your dataset only contains data for a single invoice per report.
3. Your main report dataset is called `dsMain`

---

**Assuming 1 invoice per report**

Assuming the above, as your column can only contain one of two values we can simple count how many unique values are in the dataset.

You can do something like this

```
=IIF(CountDistinct(Fields!TAXDLID.Value,"dsMain") >1, "Black", "Red")
```

---

**More than one invoice per report**

If you are producing more than one invoice per report then I would imagine you have a row group setup that groups by invoice number. If this row group is called `grpInvoice` then you need to swap out the `dsMain` scope expression for the name of your row gorup

e.g.

```
=IIF(CountDistinct(Fields!TAXDLID.Value,"grpInvoice") >1, "Black", "Red")
```

---

**Note**

The scope name MUST be the exact spelling of the row group name or dataset name, it is case sensitive AND is must be enclosed in quotes as per the example.

If this does not help, please provide a sample of the data that comes from your dataset query and your report design including grouping info where applicable.